# Send new message for all bot users

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to understand telegram api (with node js) and now got this question. Is it really to create "form" and send custom message for all who using this bot? I.e. without restarting bot send message :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is:

You need to store all the users IDs somewhere. And after that you can sendMessage to all that IDs one by one.

Comment: Thank you! And it's possibly to create something like form for sending messages?

Comment: Form in the bot dialog?

Comment: I think that's good idea. I can create 'hidden' command and push with it. Thank's for idea!